# Index of folder in wordpress .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, indexof

When I use the following url "http://www.tuto3d.netai.net/wordpress/" in my navigator I access normally my wordpress site but when I use  http://www.tuto3d.netai.net/ I get the index of folder instead and a link to wordpress folder. I want to redirect in my .htaccess the http://www.tuto3d.netai.net/ to the "http://www.tuto3d.netai.net/wordpress/"

and this is my my .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /wordpress/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thx a lot friend it works despite i did not understand the syntaxe

Comment: please friend tell me what does mean the ^$

Comment: `^$` matches an empty string (`/` is stripped by mod_rewrite in .htaccess) So essentially it will redirect `/` to `/wordpress/`